# How to pass params (action.payload) to service in ngrx/effects ?

Tags: angular6, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am new to ngrx-6.
The effects will listen to action "LOAD_COURSE_DETAILS" and should make a call to service with the course_id (action.payload). But i am getting an error

> Property 'toFixed' is missing in type 'Action'.

However, if I do console.log, I could see the data being passed from the component to the effects.

[image: add params to effects]

### **How to pass the parameters to the service?**

Thanks in advance.

---

**file: effects**

```js
@Effect()
loadCourseDetails$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(CourseActionTypes.LOAD_COURSE_DETAILS),
  switchMap((action) => {
    console.log('in course effects', action);
    return this.courseService.getCourseDetails(action).pipe(
      map((data) => new fromCourse.LoadCourseDetailsSuccess(data))
    );
  })
);
```

**file: actions.ts** (my action has payload defined)

```js
export class LoadCourseDetails implements Action {
  readonly type = CourseActionTypes.LOAD_COURSE_DETAILS;
  constructor(public payload: Number) {}
}
export class LoadCourseDetailsSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = CourseActionTypes.LOAD_COURSE_DETAILS_SUCCESS;
  constructor(public payload: ICourse) {}
}
```

**file: component.ts** (dispatch action)

```js
loadCourseDetails(id: Number) {
  console.log('dispatch course id', id);
  this.store.dispatch(new fromCourse.LoadCourseDetails(id));
}
```

file: service.ts (to be called by effeccts)

```js
getCourseDetails(courseId: Number) {
    return this.http.get(`url/${courseId}.json`);
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to use the `payload` from the `action`. 
In order to do this you'll have to fill in the generic of the `ofType` function.

Now the action inside `switchMap` is smart enough to know it's a `LoadCourseDetails` action, and thus will also known the payload type.

```
@Effect()
loadCourseDetails$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<LoadCourseDetails>(CourseActionTypes.LOAD_COURSE_DETAILS),
  switchMap((action) => {
    console.log('in course effects', action);
    return this.courseService.getCourseDetails(action.payload).pipe(
      map((data) => new fromCourse.LoadCourseDetailsSuccess(data))
    );
  })
);
```

For more effect usages, check out [Start using ngrx/effects for this](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this)

Comment: what type is action here?